# Using multiple Databases with one DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am writing a SaaS application whose data layer will run on SQL Server and be composed of one Common database, plus one Organization-type database for each company subscribing to the service.

The Common database will contain a list of users, user-to-org mappings, admin information, and so on. The Organization-type databases will contain company-specific data (e.g.: invoices and orders, if it were that kind of program).

My goal is to use a **single** `DbContext`, containing references to tables in both the Common and the Organization schema, and to have EF know at run time which one of the Org DB's to use.

Is this possible with EF6, out of the box (no hacks)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with one context, or it's atleast a real pain to be switching between contexts all the time. It sounds like the Common database is only going to be used for setup and possibly determining which Organization specific database to use. It's really not a big deal to have two contexts.

We currently switch between databases, we've edited the Model.Context.tt file (which generates the actual classes) to make the DbContext constructor get the connection string from the settings;

```
<#=Accessibility.ForType(container)#> partial class <#=code.Escape(container)#> : DbContext
{
    public <#=code.Escape(container)#>()
        : base(Properties.Settings.Default.MyContext)
{
<#
```

The `MyContext` is just the connection string, something like this;

```
"Metadata=res://*/MantraModel.csdl|res://*/MantraModel.ssdl|res://*/MantraModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;" +
                "provider connection string=\"Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Integrated Security=True;Connection Timeout={2};Persist Security Info=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework\""
```

Then, in the code, when you want to change databases, you just change the `Properties.Settings.Default.MyContext` string to be the right connection string, i.e. Common or Organization. Once `MyContext` is changed, create the context and it'll be pointing at the right Database.

Comment: Whether the Common DB will only be used for initialization purposes, i don't know yet: we're still behind in thinking of these aspects... But suppose it turns out we'll have to query and join tables in the Common DB with tables in the specific Org DB, during normal usage, I gather this can't be done in EF6, right?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use a single DataContext that contains all of the tables and then implement a Data Access Layer that restricts access to the company tables based on the logged in user.  I believe trying to do this at the DataContext layer may cause some headaches.

I had a similar problem and I implemented the standard IRepository / IUnitOfWork design pattern.  Then I implemented a "FilteredRepository" which was responsible for enforcing access restrictions between the various organizations.

Comment: I guess I haven't been clear enough. Organization tables are contained in a separate DB. There is one Org DB for each company, every one with the same schema. I want the DbContext to select, based on which DbSet I query, to select either the Common DB or the specific Org DB for querying, and also to mix them if I join tables from different databases. In SQL this is perfectly legal, I'd hoped EF supported it.

Comment: Oh, sorry about my misunderstanding.  Why do you have separate customer databases if they are the same schema?  I suspect you want to keep customer physically data separate, but a Filtered Repository will result in the same logical separation.  You might be setting up a bit of maintenance nightmare as future schema changes will have to propagated to all customer databases.

Comment: We wanted to keep separate DBs to enable granular rollbacks, in case someone manages to fubar everything with their service...